# Cloud Functions, Cloud Firestore, Cloud Storage: How to protect against bots?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-storage, recaptcha

I already use ReCAPTCHA for Android apps client-side (I've also implemented, of course, its server-side verification).

However, this ReCAPTCHA is implemented only in one activity. But, of course, hackers can modify the app. For example:

- they can simply remove ReCAPTCHA from all activities,
- or start another activity that would not have ReCAPTCHA implemented; it's the case btw: I didn't implement ReCAPTCHA in each activity because it's useless according to the first problem I've just mentioned.

So I would want to detect bot **and spam requests** in Cloud Functions, then in Cloud Firestore, then in Cloud Storage, for the following accesses: read, write, function call. It'd allow me to prevent unwanted contents from being saved in Firestore for example (spamming messages, etc.), and to avoid overreaching my monthly billing quota (because of spam requests to Firestore for example).

Is it possible? How?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no "spam detection" for these products.  Your security rules will determine who can access what data. If you don't have security rules in place, and allow public access, then anyone will be able to get that data, and you will be charged for it when that happens. This is the nature of publicly accessible cloud services.

If you want more control over the data in these products, you could stop all direct public access with security rules, and force clients to go through a backend you control.  The backend could try to apply some logic to determine if it's "spam", by whatever criteria you determine.  There is no simple algorithm for this - you will need to define what "spam" means, and reject the request if it meets you criteria.

Google does have some amount of abuse detection for its cloud products, but it will likely take a lot of abuse to trigger an alert. If you suspect abusive behavior, be sure to collect information and send that to [Firebase support](https://support.google.com/firebase/contact/support) for assistance.

Comment: Yes I already use Security Rules but the rest of your message is very useful. Thank Doug, again! I've upvoted and checked your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Just thought I'd add that there is another way to restrict access to Cloud Functions.

Doug already described Way 1, where you write the access logic within the cloud function.  In that case, the function still gets invoked, but which code path is taken is up to your logic.

Way 2 is that you can set a function to be "private" so that it *can't* be invoked except by registered users (you decide on permissions).  In this case, unauthenticated requests are denied and the function is *not* invoked at all.

Way 2 works because every Firebase project is also a Google Cloud Platform project, and GCP offers this functionality.  Here are the relevant references to (a) [Configuring functions as public/private](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/securing/managing-access-iam#controlling_access_on_a_function), and then (b) [authenticating end-users to your functions](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/securing/authenticating).